# Timsort C# разбивка на подмассивы

Tags: c#

Нужно написать тимсорт на c#. Прочитав алгоритм, я начал реализовывать его, но столкнулся с проблемой. Как мне разбить массив на подмассивы?

**Кто не знает принцип работы тимсорта**: Берётся массив, и идёт проверка на отсортированные части в массиве, и разбиваются на подмассивы.

*Пример:*
Входной массив: [1, 5, 8, 4, 3, 0, 7, 3, 2]
Получившиеся подмассивы: [1, 5, 8], [4, 3, 0], [7, 3, 2]

Comment: Во-первых, это описывалось в статье на [хабре](https://habr.com/en/company/infopulse/blog/133303/). Во-вторых, если вы не понимаете как разбить -- то вы можете просто разбить "абы как" для начала, а потом уже улучшать неясные места в алгоритме. Просто пишите код, а не бросайте на очередной трудности. Вот и сейчас - могли бы приложить код, есть он у вас?

Comment: @AK Я читал эту статью. Я не понимаю как мне разбить. Кода у меня нет, т.к. я не совсем понимаю алгоритм. В моём представлении код выглядел так: бежим по массиву, если элемент по индексу i < i + 1 или i >= i + 1, то мы создаём новый массив и добавляем в него элемент, дальше идёт проверка на длину... Но проблема в том, что каждый раз будет создаваться массив с 1 элементом, а заранее создать массивы нельзя, т.к. мы не знаем сколько их будет. Да и по условия в массив будут добавлены все элементы, так что придётся создавать 2 условия.

Comment: Вам не нужно создавать массивы. Пользуйтесь вместо этого исходным массивом, и запоминайте индексы начала и конца.

Comment: Тимсорт - это про скорость. Создание подмассивов тут абсолютно не нужно. Пусть ваши методы принимают на входе исходный массив и диапазон индексов, с которым работать. Поглядите реализацию сортировки слиянием (или другой аналогичной), там подобный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Я не подскажу вам как реализовать алгоритм, но разбить массив на подмассивы можно с помощью LINQ:

```
var array = new int[] { 5, 3, 8, 9, 6 ,4};
var subarrays = array
    .Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3) // тут 3 - это длинна одного подмассива
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
    
subarrays
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(subarray => Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(",", subarray) + "]"));
```

Вывод:

```
[5,3,8]
[9,6,4]
```

Comment: чет лично я как-то не особо понимаю как именно работает строка GroupBy в даном случае. Можешь обьяснить?

Comment: А, понял. 1,2,3 при делении на 3 будет 1; 3,4,5 при делении на 3 будет 2, И по этим значениям мы групируем. Блин, прикольно

Comment: @Andrew практически. `0, 1 и 2` при делении на 3 будет `0` (округляется до целых), `3, 4, 5` / 3 = `1` и т.д.

Comment: а ну да, округление до меньшего)

Comment: Да в принципе этот линковский алгоритм можно и буквально слизать и получить тот же результат без линка вообще не думая)